# Shortcut to get out of bracket or parenthesis in iPython

Tags: ipython, shortcut, parentheses, brackets, text-cursor

Is there a shortcut to moving the cursor from

```
my_variable = (entry|)
```

to

```
my_variable = (entry)
|
```

in iPython notebook? Where "|" is the cursor

That is, is there some shortcut you can use in place of (right arrow) followed by (return) in iPython to get out of the automatic parentheses/brackets? I feel like it would be useful to have this when coding really fast.

Comment: There isn't one built into IPython. It's probably possible to add something to your custom.js to make it work, but I'm not exactly sure how. Have a look at [these extensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/wiki/Home_3x#usability) for ideas.

Comment: Excellent question. How to make a shortcut to accept iPython suggestions for parentheses, brackets, colons... and move text insertion point forward?

Answer (score 0):

I found pressing 'End' & 'Enter' does the work.

Answer (score 0):

yups, you can just hit shift plus the closing round braket once more like so ) that is 'shift + )' and you will get out of the round brackets for example lets say you type round braket and it automatically closes with your cursor in the middle of the two braket like the following (|) now to get out of it you need to press the 'shift + )' once more and your cursor will be ()| outside
I hope this helps
also its the same for other curly brakets and square brakets